# Sumproduct on multiple array conditions

Tags: arrays, excel

In my other post, I learned that I can use array-conditions as long I use a horizontal condition in a vertical array. For example, this will work:

```
X1=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100=C1:D1)*(B1:B100))
```

Now I see that I can add even more conditions, but I could not figure out how to add an extra array condition. For example, this would also work:

```
X2 =SUMPRODUCT((E1:E100=C2)*(A1:A100=C1:D1)*(B1:B100))
```

But this gives me the wrong result (it is less than expected):

```
X3 =SUMPRODUCT((E1:E100=C2:D2)*(A1:A100=C1:D1)*(B1:B100))
```

And any other array gives me error messages:

```
X4 =SUMPRODUCT((E1:E100=C2:E2)*(A1:A100=C1:D1)*(B1:B100)) =ERROR
```

Because I get less than expected on X3 I guess that there is some boolean condition between my calculation in "(E1: E100=C2: D2)" and "(A1: A100=C1: D1)". I do not see it, though. Especially I thought that In case of X4 where greatest common divisor of the length of my conditional arrays is 1, I did not think such boolean problems occur. Can you help me out?

Many greetings,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility here is to use `MATCH` to compare against a range/array, e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(E1:E100,C2:D2,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A100,C1:D1,0)),B1:B100)`

This is more flexible in that it allows any number of array conditions....and each of them can be either a column or row of any length  (but only single columns or rows), so we can change `C1:D1` to `C1:Z1` with no problems

Comment: Thanks. This answer is more flexible, so I prefer this one. Both answers work.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMIFS() and one of the arrays needs to be horizontal and the other vertical, so use transpose.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B1:B100,E1:E100,C2:D2,A1:A100,TRANSPOSE(C1:D1)))
```

Comment: Holy shit. I did not know that sumproduct can help sumifs out of it's problem that it cannot handle array-conditions. Thanks.

PS: is two arrays the end of the line or can you go on with more array conditions?

Comment: Two is the max.